# How can I programmatically create an argument for calling a custom function

Tags: powerbi

I create a custom function `MyCustomFunction` and I populate a table by calling it with a hard code string `= MyCustomFunction("2023-01-31 09:00:00.000")

MyCustomFunction is

```
= (aDate as text) => 
let 
   Source = 
   ....
in Source
```

My question is instead of passing in a hard code string, how can I programmatically construct a string which is 1 month ago and then call the custom function?

I tried doing `VAR` in the `Source`

```
= 
VAR _month = MONTH(NOW() - 1)
VAR _day = DAY(NOW())
VAR _year = YEAR(NOW())
MyCustomFunction(_year + "-" + _month + "-" + _day + " 09:00:00.000")
```

But PowerBI complains about my `VAR _month` in the code

with error `Expression.SyntaxError: Token Eof expected.`

Comment: You're mixing Power Query M and DAX which are completely different languages with different purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Power Query custom functions written in M in code written in DAX.

Considering the error you got, you tried to write DAX code in Power Query editor, where the language should be M.

Your code should be something like this:

```
= MyCustomFunction(DateTime.ToText(
    DateTime.From(
        Date.AddDays(
            DateTime.Date(DateTimeZone.UtcNow()),
             -1)
             ) 
             + #duration(0, 9, 0, 0),
    [Format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", Culture="en-US"]))
```

[image]

One last thing - make the type the parameter of your function to be date instead of text. Convert the date to the desired format in the function itself.